# Design Installation screen like Google Play

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have an intent to develop the installation screen like Google Play. Now, I'm stuck at the beginning because of one problem.

I don't know how to design this view like following picture.

[image: img]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What does your layout look like right now?

Comment: Hi @Blaasd, thanks for your respone. I just want to create custom view like the above picture. I use this view to show my app's information like a number of download, rating, ...

Comment: What does your attempt currently look like?

Comment: Regarding the contents or your post... Please read why ["Can someone help me" is not an actual question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @cricket_007: thanks for you advise. I will follow this guide in the future :D

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried the first item. The next items, I think you need you svg or png as a background.

[image]

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/corner_red_stroke">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="10"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_red_solid"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MILLION"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="8sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**corner_red_solid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#ff0105"/>
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff0105" />

</shape>
```

**corner_red_stroke.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff0105" />

</shape>
```

Comment: This answer is so awesome. Thank you so much for your answer. You save my day :D